# Determine mouse button release in LWJGL

Tags: java, mouse, lwjgl

I have a program in LWJGL where I have a series of buttons. I'm trying to use `Mouse.getEventButton()` and `Mouse.getEventButtonState()` in order to figure out when the mouse is *released*, but neither seem to be working. After adding a few print statements for debugging, it seems that `getEventButton()` always returns 0 regardless of what the mouse is doing, and `getEventButtonState()` always returns false. All other mouse methods I've used so far have behaved normally. Any idea what might be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by analogy with keyboard as described [in this tutorial](http://ninjacave.com/lwjglbasics2).

```
while (Mouse.next()){
    if (Mouse.getEventButtonState()) {
        if (Mouse.getEventButton() == 0) {
            System.out.println("Left button pressed");
        }
    }else {
        if (Mouse.getEventButton() == 0) {
            System.out.println("Left button released");
        }
    }
}
```