# Event fired multiple times - LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, events, mouse, lwjgl

I'm making a 3D game engine, and i've made my own way of handing events fired and passing them to each `GuiComponent` until its either returned true (handled), or it gets through them all, in which case it disposes the event.

The issue is, the events are firing more than one. I have made sure i'm not creating multiple instances of the `eventHandler` class. I though perhaps the `Mouse` class in `LWJGL` fires multiple times? If not, what is wring with the current setup? Thanks

EventHandler:

```
public abstract interface EventHandler {
    public abstract boolean handleEvent(Event event);
}
```

Event:

```
public class Event {

    public enum events {
        MOUSEPRESSED, MOUSEDRAGGED, MOUSEMOVED
    }

    private events event;

    public float x, y;

    public Event(events event, float x, float y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = DisplayManager.HEIGHT - y;
        this.event = event;
    }

    public Event setPos(float x, float y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = DisplayManager.HEIGHT - y;
        return this;
    }

    public void setEvent(events event) {
        this.event = event;
    }

    public boolean equals(events event) {
        return event.equals(this.event);
    }
}
```

GuiButton:

```
public class GuiButton extends GuiComponent implements EventHandler {

    @Override
    public boolean passEvent(Event event) {
        if (!visible) return false;
        if (event.equals(Event.events.MOUSEPRESSED) && super.passEvent(event)) {
            texture = texture2;
            return handleEvent(event);
        } else texture = texture1;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleEvent(Event event) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

GuiPanel:

```
public class GuiPanel extends GuiComponent {

    protected List<GuiComponent> components = new ArrayList<GuiComponent>();

    @Override
    public boolean passEvent(Event event) {
        for (GuiComponent c : components) {
            if (c.passEvent(event)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
        super.setVisible(visible);
        for (GuiComponent c : components) c.setVisible(visible);
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
        for (GuiComponent c : components) {
            if (c.isVisible()) c.update();
        }
    }
```

GuiComponent:

```
public abstract class GuiComponent extends Rectangle {

    public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
        this.visible = visible;
    }

    public boolean isVisible() {
        return visible;
    }

    public boolean passEvent(Event event) {
        if (this.contains(event.x, event.y)) return true;
        return false;
    }

    public abstract void update();
}
```

Component creation:

```
    main = new GuiPanel(0, 0, 100, DisplayManager.HEIGHT, "null", loader);
    guiCompoents.add(main);

    entityPanel = new GuiPanel(30, 100, 100, 300, "null", loader);

    b2 = new GuiButton(100, 100, 100, 30, "Entitiesn", "Entitiesh2", loader) {
        public boolean handleEvent(Event event) {
            if (event.equals(Event.events.MOUSEPRESSED)) {
                System.out.println("button2 recieved event");
                createEntity(tree1);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
    entityPanel.add(b2);
    entityPanel.setVisible(false);

    b1 = new GuiButton(30, 100, 100, 30, "Entitiesn", "Entitiess", loader) {
        public boolean handleEvent(Event event) {
            if (event.equals(Event.events.MOUSEPRESSED)) {
                System.out.println("button1 recieved event");
                entityPanel.setVisible(!entityPanel.isVisible());
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
    main.add(b1);

    main.add(entityPanel);
```

EDIT:
Okay, upon further searching, I tried the following where i'm detecting events firing:

```
if (Mouse.getDX() != 0 || Mouse.getDY() != 0) {
        event.setEvent(Event.events.MOUSEMOVED);
        event.setPos(Mouse.getX(), Mouse.getY());
        passEvent(event);
    }
```

And the event is fired multiple times. The `Mouse` class is inbuilt into `LWJGL`, so this seems to be the problem. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I am not LWJGL expert but I had similar problem yesterday with Libgdx. Are your gui elements overlapping each other?

Comment: @Sneh Yes, but the event is only passed on/handled if its in bounds, and that is only checked if the component contains another component. The issue is that one button receives the click event 6 times

Comment: That's wierd, sorry I cannot help you then :(

Comment: @Sneh thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after searching around, I came across this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906841/determine-mouse-button-release-in-lwjgl), which fixes the issue. I'm not entirely sure why, I shall take a look at the documentation for the `Mouse` class, but this seems to work and only fires the event once, and it gives me a released event, which is awesome. Hope this helps someone else in the future! There was nothing about this issue specifically anywhere on the internet.